# Fixing black screen

Tags: dell, laptop, screen

I dont know why Dell redictered me to you guys but I'm having issues with my laptop and I'm hoping you can help. A few hours ago I restarted it and when it came back on it loaded and just showed a black screen with the cursor on it. I spent 50 minutes on the phone with someone from Dell, nothing worked.

I'm hoping you can help me.

Comment: Please consider review your question and providing more information about your laptop, What you were doing before restarting the computer? Have you notice something in particular? http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I found two solution depending on your graphic card try them.

If your graphics card is **Nvidia**, follow these steps:

1. In the GRUB menu at startup, press <kbd>e</kbd>; then,
2. Use the arrow keys to replace `quiet splash` with `no splash` or `nomodeset`.
3. Then press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> key combination to boot.

If your graphics card is **ATI**, follow these steps:

1. In the GRUB menu at startup, press "e"; then
2. Use the arrow keys to replace `quiet splash` with `radeon.modeset=0`.
3. Then press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> key combination to boot.

Comment: It is intel unfortunately... But thanks for takinh the time to answer